# ¿Como puedo ejecutar un metodo durante unos 10 minutos en Android y luego de ese tiempo deje de ejecutarse?

Tags: java, android

Como podría hacer, que por ejemplo un método o condición se ejecute unos minutos y luego deje de funcionar cuando se cumpla el tiempo limite.

Comment: tienes que saber que si la persona cierra la aplicación se cancela la ejecución tienes que hacerlo en segundo plano, aun así creo que tienes un limite.

Comment: es un metodo que tarda poco y tienes que ejecutarlo varias veces? o es continuo y tienes que pararlo al pasar 10 minutos?

Comment: ¿Necesitas que este método se ejecute en el hilo principal o que se ejecute en background? ¿Este método puede ser ejecutado en paralelo? ¿Deben haber mecanismos para cancelar la ejecución del método? ¿Qué sucede si hay una excepción: el método debe dejar de funcionar o debería tratar de continuar repitiendo su ejecución?

Comment: @JordiCastilla Digamos que le doy click a un boton y el metodo debe ejecutarse en background durante 2 minutos y ya està.

Comment: @JDeveloper eso lo entiendo, pero no has respondido a mi pregunta, tienes muchas ejecuciones de un mismo metodo que dejaran de lanzarse al llegar el limite o por el contrario tienes un metodo infinito que debes parar pasado el tiempo?

Answer (score 1):

Si buscas que un método se ejecute varias veces durante 10 minutos, puedes hacerlo como lo dice Elenasys, pero si quieres ejecutar un método, quizás que tenga un cíclo, entonces quizás necesites utilizar `Thread`.

```
public class miThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public run() {
       //Tu método
    }
}
```

Y fuera de esa clase, lo que hizo Elenasys, pero intentando parar el Thread.

```
try{
   mithread.stop();
}catch(InterruptedException e) {}
```

De modo que el try se ejecute despues de los 10 minutos.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una forma de crear una cuenta regresiva en tu caso de 10 a 0:

```
new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
  }.start();
```

Answer (score -2):

Esta es una forma de lograr lo que deseas:

```
long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
long terminacion = inicio + 600*1000; // 600 segundos * 1000 millisegundos
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < terminacion)
{
    // ejecuta metodo.
}
//termina método después de 10 minutos.
```